# PLS-00103: "variable_name" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ;

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I can't figure out what's wrong with my procedure but I keep getting this error on a particular line that doesn't seem to have any mistakes.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE procedure set_new_planned(cons_id NUMBER, proj_id NUMBER, p_c_hrs NUMBER)
  2  AS
  3  proj_cons_dta number(3,1);
  4  proj_cons_hrs number(3,1);
  5  proj_cons_c_id number(3,1);
  6  proj_cons_p_id number(3,1);
  7  BEGIN
  8      ACCEPT proj_cons_c_id number PROMPT "Enter value for consultant_id: ";
  9      ACCEPT proj_cons_p_id number PROMPT "Enter value for project_id: ";
 10      ACCEPT proj_cons_dta number PROMPT "Enter value for change_in_hours: ";
 11      SELECT c_id FROM project_consultant WHERE  proj_cons_c_id = c_id;
 12      SELECT p_id FROM project_consultant WHERE  proj_cons_p_id = p_id;
 13      SELECT total_hours FROM project_consultant WHERE c_id := proj_cons_c_id AND p_id = proj_cons_p_id;
 14      proj_cons_hrs:= proj_cons_dta + total_hours;
 15      dbms_output.put_line('Consultant ' || proj_cons_c_id || ' Project ' || proj_cons_p_id || ' Changed planned hours from ' || total_hours ' to ' || proj_cons_hrs);
 16      UPDATE project_consultant SET total_hours = proj_cons_hrs WHERE c_id = proj_cons_c_id AND p_id = proj_cons_p_id;
 17  COMMIT;
 18  END set_new_planned;
 19  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show error
Errors for PROCEDURE SET_NEW_PLANNED:

LINE/COL ERROR                                                                  
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------      
8/12     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROJ_CONS_C_ID" when expecting      
         one of the following:                                                  
         := . ( @ % ;
```

Comment: please do not modify the question. Post a new  question if you have a new question.

Comment: My apologies for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACCEPT is a SQL*Plus command, you can't use it in PL/SQL procedure.

So: create a procedure, specify its parameters; when calling the procedure, provide their values. For example:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in number) is
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    select count(*)
  5      into l_cnt
  6      from emp
  7      where deptno = par_deptno;
  8
  9    dbms_output.put_line('Number of employees in department ' || par_deptno || ': ' || l_cnt);
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    p_test(&deptno);
  3  end;
  4  /
Enter value for deptno: 10
Number of employees in department 10: 3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ACCEPT` is a SQL*Plus command, not a PL/SQL statement. It's not valid in the context of a PL/SQL procedure.

Comment: ACCEPT is valid in the context of a PL/SQL procedure but it is not interpreted as SQL*Plus command but as identifier.

Comment: @miracle173: good point.  I would have better said that `ACCEPT` is not a valid *statement* in a PL/SQL procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In your code at Line number 13;

You have missed "||" to put before 'to'

```
dbms_output.put_line('Consultant ' || proj_cons_c_id || ' Project ' || proj_cons_p_id || ' Changed planned hours from ' || proj_cons_init || ' to ' || proj_cons_hrs);
```

Comment: that is one of the additional errors in the code but not the reason for the error message.

Comment: sorry,  see now that you anwered the modified question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel really silly for missing that but now my procedure doesn't cause an error.